# How do I use Strings in if statements?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

*note: sorry about the bad formatting, I'm new to stack overflow*

If I had a piece of code that started like this,

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyProgram
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner Input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println( "Write either yes or no." );
    String message = Input.nextLine();
```

and wanted to check the String variable "message"'s contents in an if statements, how would I do that?

I am thinking about something like this:

```
if( message == "yes" )
```

By this, I mean checking what the user wrote when prompted to, which is stored as message.

Comment: Use `.equals` method instead of `==` operator. here is [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)